# CSRF protection while making use of server side caching

Tags: http, security, caching, csrf, same-origin-policy

#### Situation

There is a site at `examp.le` that costs a lot of CPU/RAM to generate and a more lean `examp.le/backend` that will perform various tasks to read, write and serve user-specific data for authenticated requests. A lot of resources could be saved by utilizing a server side cache on the `examp.le` site but not on `examp.le/backend` and just asynchronously grab all user-specific data from the backend once the page arrives at the client. (Total loading time may even be lower, despite the need of an additional request.)

#### Threat model

CSRF attacks. Assuming (*maybe foolishly*) that `examp.le` is reliably safeguarded against XSS code injection, we still need to consider scripts on malicious site `exploit.me` that cause the victims browser to run a request against `examp.le/backend` with their authorization cookies included automagically and cause the server to perform some kind of data mutation on behalf of the user.

#### Solution / problem with that

As far as I understand, the  commonly used countermeasure is to include another token in the generated `exampl.le` page. The server can verify this token is linked to the current user's session and will only accept requests that can provide it. But I assume caching won't work very well if we are baking a random token into every response to `examp.le`..?

#### So then...

I see two possible solutions: One would be some sort of "hybrid caching" where each response to `examp.le` is still programmatically generated but that program is just merging small dynamic parts to some cached output. Wouldn't work with caching systems that work on the higher layers of the server stack, let alone a CDN, but still might have its merits. I don't know if there is a standard ways or libraries to do this, or more specifically if there are solutions for wordpress (which happens to be the culprit in my case).

The other (preferred) solution would be to get an initial anti-CSRF token directly from `examp.le/backend`. But I'm not quite clear in my understanding about the implications of that. If the script on `exploit.me` could somehow obtain that token, the whole mechanism would make no sense to begin with. The way I understand it, *if we leave exploitable browser bugs and security holes out of the picture and consider only requests coming from a non-obscure browser visiting `exploit.me`*, then the `HTTP_ORIGIN` header can be absolutely trusted to be tamper proof. Is that correct? But then that begs the question: wouldn't we get mostly the same amount of security in this scenario by only checking authentication cookie and origin header, without throwing tokens back and forth?

*I'm sorry if this question feels a bit all over the place, but I'm partly still in the process of getting the whole picture clear ;-)*

Comment: sorry I thought that was clear but it was in fact not, so I updated the question. only the expensive frontpage is supposed to be cached, requests to the `examp.le/backend` are never cached since they will rarely yield the same results

Comment: That is more clear, thanks. Basically, you're looking for ways to protect `examp.le/backend` from CSRF without having to send a token in the response to `examp.le` (to allow that page to be served from the cache). Right?

Comment: There are a number of ways to do that, see the OWASP page. You could use a dedicated endpoint for the CSRF token, you could use a [custom header](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html#use-of-custom-request-headers) in JS calls to `backend`, you could [check referrer or origin](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html#verifying-origin-with-standard-headers), and more.

Comment: thanks. I've done some more reading. So a script on *other origin* running in the (correctly working) browser of an unsuspecting victim doing a XHR to *my origin* will never be able to include custom headers nor manipulate the origin header in that request. So even just denying requests that don't includef e.g. `X-MY-TRUSTY-HEADER` in `examp.le/backend` would be pretty reliable?

Comment: Right. And most client libraries already send `X-Requested-With` so you probably don't even need a new header.

Answer (score 2):

First of all: Cross-Site Scripting (XSS) and Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF) are two different categories of attacks. I assume, you meant to tackle CSRF problem only.

Second of all: it's crucial to understand what CSRF is about. Consider following.

1. A POST request to `exampl.le/backend` changes some kind of crucial data
2. The request to `exampl.le/backend` is protected by authentication mechanisms, which generate valid session cookies.
3. I want to attack you. I do it by sending you a link to a page I have forged at `cats.com\best_cats_evr`.
4. If you are logged in to `exampl.le` in one browser tab and you open `cats.com\best_cats_evr` in another, the code will be executed.
5. The code on the site `cats.com\best_cats_evr` will send a POST request to `exampl.le/backend`. The cookies will be attached, as there is not reason why they should not. You will perform a change on `exampl.le/backend` without knowing it.

So, having said that, how can we prevent such attacks?

The CSRF case is very well known to the community and it makes little sense for me to write everything down myself. Please check the [OWASP CSRF Prevention Cheat Sheet](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html), as it is one of the best pages you can find in this topic.

And yes, checking the origin would help in this scenario. But checking the origin will not help, if I find XSS vulnerability in `exampl.le/somewhere_else` and use it against you.

What would also help would be not using POST requests (as they can be manipulated without origin checks), but use e.g. PUT where CORS should help... But this quickly turns out to be too much of rocket science for the dev team to handle and sticking to good old anti-CSRF tokens (supported by default in every framework) should help.

Comment: thanks for the answer. it doesn't directly address my specific problem but led to some more insights. Would you mind explaining (or pointing to an explanation) what you mean by POST requests can be manipulated without origin checks? I don't quite get that...

Comment: POST request can be made by creating HTML forms and sending them. Forms can generate requests to any domain. But you can't generate e.g. PUT requests with forms. You would need to do it with JavaScript. But you can't communicate with any domain using JS unless CORS headers allow it. Hope this helps.